# Montrer du doigt la responsabilité — why not “de la” or “à la”?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, phrase

I have learned this phrase some time ago and since it has been sounding strange. The beginning is all fine « montrer du doigt » and I’m expecting to hear something more than just a specific responsibility. Is « le doigt la responsabilité » a phrase in French, maybe?

I'm confused by the "...doigt la responsabilité" rather than the "du doigt". It sounds like someone dropped one "de" in front of "la". "...doigt de la responsabilité" sounds more correct. Is there a phrase that has a construction "[verb] du/de la [object] le/la [noun"?

For example, in the phrase "Tirer des leçons de la situation", there's "de" in front of "la". Or "Prendre du recul sur la situation", again there's "sur" before "la", or "Changer du tout au tout"...

Comment: Does it sound strange because there's a prepositional phrase between the verb and the direct object? Would "Montrer la responsabilité du doigt" sound better? If this is the case, you're taking English rules (or more precisely, guidelines) and applying them to French. Of course, if English isn't your first language, my comment may be completely off-base.

Comment: @PeterShor Indeed splitting the prepositional phrase from the verb is not a problem in French. But as far as the question goes I'm not sure what it's really asking.

Comment: *La responsabilité* is the direct objet of *montrer*, so there should be no preposition between the verb and the object. *Du doigt* is a circumstantial complement, *montrer du doigt* means the same than *montrer avec le doigt* (but we don't say that).

Comment: Does this [dictionary entry](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/montrer_du_doigt) help in any way? Or [this one](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/montrer-du-doigt)?

Comment: It's possible to say also _montrer la responsabilité du doigt_, which brings the direct object closer to the verb _montrer_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start from this sentence :

> On montre du doigt la responsabilité des paysans dans la gestion de l'eau.

We can split the sentence thus:

- *On montre du doigt* where *du doigt* is a circumstantial complement. [Montrer du doigt](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/montrer_du_doigt) is a phrase in which *du doigt* means *avec le doigt* (but we don't say *avec le doigt*).
- *la responsabilité des paysans* is the direct object of *montrer*. *Montrer* is a transitive verb and as such is followed by a direct object (which means there is no preposition between the verb and the object).

One can say *montrer du doigt quelque chose* or *montrer quelque chose du doigt*, the object can be placed indifferently, but not all the time, it mostly depends on its length. In my example I would not split *montrer* from *du doigt* because the object is rather long. It's often a matter of feeling.

*Tirer des leçons de quelque chose* is a different construction.
We have the verb *tirer* which has a direct objet: *des leçons*, and a circumstantial complement : *de la situation* : *on tire **de** quelque chose*, this *de* means "from". The same with *prendre du recul sur la situation*, *du recul* is a circumstantial complement introduced by the preposition *sur*. In the above example *la responsabilité* is not a circumstantial complement but the direct object of the verb (whereas *du doigt* could be said to be a circumstantial complement).